# Drag,Zoom or Rotate an ImageView

Tags: android, image, matrix

[Here](https://github.com/judepereira/android-multitouch/blob/master/src/com/multitouch/example/MultiTouch.java) is a class which performs Drag, Zoom and Rotate of an **ImageView**.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/butterfly" />

</FrameLayout>
```

But it was all done on the **Matrix** of the **ImageView** using the `imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`

Not the actual image view.

Hence the below results:

**Initial ImageView:**

[image]

**On Dragging right:**

[image]

**On Zooming in:**

[image]

**On Rotating:**

[image]

Is there a way I can modify the **ImageView** to change as per it's **Matrix**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `View.setRotation()`, `View.setPivotX()`, `View.setPivotY()`, `View.setScaleX()`, `View.setScaleY()`, `View.setTranslationX()` and `View.setTranslationY()` ond any View including an `ImageView`.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to translate the imageView? If not you can use  [setRectToRect (RectF src, RectF dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit stf)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit%29) to show the translated image centered in the original view.

```
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

for drag , calculate the distance moved and add it to the left and top margin

like this

```
x = event.getRawX();
y = event.getRawY();

parms.leftMargin = (int) ((x - dx) + scalediff);
parms.topMargin = (int) ((y - dy) + scalediff);
```

and for zooming you can use ScaleX and ScaleY methods

```
view.setScaleX(scale);
view.setScaleY(scale);
```

and for rotation

```
view.animate().rotationBy(angle).setDuration(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

Comment: This code behaves unexpectedly when used with different parent layouts like ConstraintLayout, after rotate image 180 degree and start the drag, view rapidly starts moves and disappears from the screen. Working on the fix will post soon.